# Define equality based on class property to be used in HashSet

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class OrderRule {
  public OrderDirection Direction { get; set; }
  public String Property { get; set; }
}
```

And an HashSet of it:

```
HashSet<OrderRule> rules = // ...
```

I need to OrderRules to be considered equal if the Property is equal.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to implement Equals and GetHashCode methods

Comment: What prevents you from implementing it in the way you've mentioned?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If I add two OrderRules with same Property but different Direction I still need both to be considered equal.

Comment: you need to override the Equals method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the specification for this equality is not coming from the OrderRule class, but your collection, use the constructor overload of the HashSet that accepts an IEqualityComparer.

```
public class MyOrderRuleComparer : EqualityComparer<OrderRule>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<string> _c = EqualityComparer<string>.Default;

    public override bool Equals(OrderRule l, OrderRule r)
    {
        return _c.Equals(l.Property, r.Property);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(OrderRule rule)
    {
        return _c.GetHashCode(rule.Property);
    }
}
```

...

```
HashSet<OrderRule> rules = new HashSet(new MyOrderRuleComparer());
```

Please note that by using OrderRule.Property as a key, you imply that it must not change after the instance is added to the set. This is why implementing `IEquatable<OrderRule>` could be the best approach depending on your developer team.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply write `public bool Equals(OrderRule l, OrderRule r) { return l.Property == r.Property; }` but instead use an explicit reference to the default `IEqualityComparer<string>`?

Comment: Btw, I like the idea to restrict that definition of "equality" to the HashSet (instead of overriding equality for the whole class, which may be inappropriate in other places). I didn't know HashSet can do that. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: It is just a matter of style, I guess. This way I leave it to the .NET framework implementors to know how to implement this IEqualityComparer<string> instead of copying the current implementation from the framework.

Comment: "Matter of style": Well, I'm glad there is no `IHashcodeProvider<string>` or I would have learned about that one as well ... ;-).

Answer (score 3):

> If I add two OrderRules with same Property but different Direction I
>   still need both to be considered equal

You could override `Equals` and `GethashCode` and/or implement `IEquatable<OrderRule>`:

```
public class OrderRule: IEquatable<OrderRule>
{
    public OrderRule(string property)
    {
        this.Property = property;
    }

    public OrderDirection Direction { get; set; }
    public String Property { get; }
    public OrderRule Rule { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(OrderRule other)
    {
        return (other != null && other.Property == this.Property);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Property?.GetHashCode() ?? int.MinValue;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if(ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        OrderRule other = obj as OrderRule;
        return this.Equals(other);
    }
}
```

Note that i've made the property read-only because you should not be able to modify a property or field that is used in `GetHashCode`.

[Why?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/): *"Guideline: the integer returned by GetHashCode should never change
Ideally, the hash code of a mutable object should be computed from only fields which cannot mutate, and therefore the hash value of an object is the same for its entire lifetime."*

This value is f.e. used in a dictionary or HashSet to compute the hashcode. If it would change after the object was added it could no  longer be found.

Comment: I like that you mention that Property should be immutable if we use it as the key in the hash.